# Reset an object

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, copy-and-swap

Lately I often reset an object by assigning a new value to it with `operator=`. Most of my classes have a `copy constructor` and `operator=` defined using "copy and swap" idiom. Which works fine in most cases, albeit not as efficient as it could be, but that mostly does not matter. There is one case that this does not work though. Its when the `destructor` needs to be called before the `constructor` of the new object.

Note: most of the classes for which I use this are uncopyable

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : m_i(0) {}
    Foo(int i) : m_i(i) {}

    Foo(Foo&& rhs);
    Foo& operator=(Foo rhs);
    friend void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs);

private:
    Foo(Foo& rhs) {}    // uncopyable object

    int m_i;
};

Foo::Foo(Foo&& rhs)
: Foo()
{
    swap(*this, rhs);
}

Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo rhs)
{
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}

void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.m_i, rhs.m_i);
}

int main()
{
    Foo f(123);
    f = Foo(321);   // at one time both Foo(123) and Foo(321) exist in memory
}
```

I have then taught to maybe rewrite `operator=` to first manually call the `destructor` and then do the `swap` (in this case `rhs` would be taken by const reference). However [this answer on stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187068/1771055) made me think otherwise.

I really like operator= to reset my objects, becuase the code is clean and is the same as for built in types (like int). It also uses both the code from `constructor` and `destructor`, so no extra code needs to be written and maintained.

So my question is: Is there a way to achieve my goal to reset my object with clean code and no extra code to be written and have the object be destructed before the new one is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if you *assign* a new value to an old object, the new value has been constructed before the assignment can take place.

Your 'old object' is not really destructed, either.

So No.  There is no way.  And there shouldn't: you shouldn't redefine the 'obvious' behavior of the assignment operator.

But placement new could help here apart from the tilde and exotic construction syntax, maybe this code approaches 'clean' :)

```
Foo old(a, b, c);
old.~Foo(); // explicit destruction
new (&old) Foo(d, e, f);
```

Comment: I could work with writing a reset() method using the placement new syntax. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you have code in the constructor that needs to also be called by the assignment operator, then put that code in a private member function and call that from both the destructor and the assignment operator.

You object won't be destructed (and you don't want it to be really), but it will do the same thing as the destructor.

Comment: As you can see from the example, there is no code in the body of the  constructor. Yet the variable `m_i` is initialized. I guess that the variable could be set in the body of the constructor, but that is not always possible or desirable. What is the general approach to resetting objects?