# New to Destructors (C++)

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm new to destructors, and the tutorials i've been following have been pretty clear up until this point. What actually happens when a destructor is called? Why do I still get values from a destroyed object?

```
class Box {

public: 
    Box(double l = 2.0, double b = 2.0, double h = 2.0) {   //Constructor
        cout << "Box Created" << endl;
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
        height = h;
    }
    ~Box() {
        cout << "Box Destroyed" << endl; // Box Destructor
    }
        double volume() {
            return length*breadth*height;
        }

private:
    double height;
    double breadth;
    double length;

};
void main() {

    Box Box1(10, 15, 5);    //Constructors used
    Box Box2(5, 15, 20);

    cout << "Box1.volume: " << Box1.volume() << endl;
    cout << "Box2.volume: " << Box2.volume() << endl;
    Box1.~Box(); //Destructors called
    Box2.~Box();
    cout << "Box1.volume after destruction: " << Box1.volume() << endl;
    cout << "Box2.volume after destruction: " << Box2.volume() << endl;



}
```

Comment: You don't want to call the destructors explicitly.  Since your objects are allocated on the stack, the destructors will be called automatically when your function returns.

Comment: @RJM Not all objects are created on the stack, but your point is still valid.

Comment: You should hardly ever call a destructor explicitly, and box1 & 2 here are automatic variables, in this case destructors are called when the scope leaves the bloc.

Comment: @PW. s/hardly never/hardly ever

Comment: @Marcus Muller - Of course they're not all allocated on the stack.  That's why I qualified my comment by pointing out that the OPs objects are allocated on the stack.  :-)

Comment: @RJM He most likely meant the common misconception of "stored on the stack" vs. "stored on the heap". From the standard's point of view, that's an implementation detail, it does not care where the implementation stores the data. In C++ standardese, the distinction "automatic storage duration" vs. "dynamic storage duration" vs. "static storage duration" should be made instead, with normal local variables falling into the first category.

Comment: @OP `void main` is wrong, `main` must always return `int`. Flowing off the end of `main` implicitly returns a "value indicating successful termination" (aka. 0).

Comment: @RJM Actually, probably not. vOv

Comment: @OP - *and the tutorials i've been following* -- No tutorials I know of would show calling the destructor explicitly.  There is a reason for that, and you've found out why.

Answer (score -2):

You **never** call a destructor explicitely, unless you know very well you need to because you're handling the life-time and allocation of your objects yourself, which, typically, is a not very C++-like approach.

Destructors are meant to be called automatically, when the lifetime of a C++ objects ends, for example, when an object goes out of scope.

A destructor's job is to "clean up" before the C++ runtime frees the memory associated with that object. Calling a destructor explicitly doesn't "remove" the object – it just brings the object into some kind of "Zombie" state.

As a beginner, generalizing: Don't call destructors explicitely.

Comment: Well, you would call it explicitly if you were using [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new).

Comment: Wrong. You do call destructors explicitly in a certain scenarios.

Comment: See [Is calling destructor manually always a sign of bad design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187006/is-calling-destructor-manually-always-a-sign-of-bad-design)

Comment: @flatmouse: There's a lot of reasons *not* to use placement new, and the linked article even states **ADVICE: Don’t use this “placement new” syntax unless you have to**

Comment: "unless you have to" != "never"

Comment: Another wrong statement. Good luck creating meaningful custom allocator without using placement new.

Comment: @stuartd: agreeing with that answer: **Outside managing memory on a rather low level as above calling destructors explicitly, however, is a sign of bad design**

Comment: @flatmouse agreed, "never" might be a tad to strong. But OP is definitely a beginner, and people who don't write custom allocators, as mentioned by the answer stuartd linked to, shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Within the context of this question I would agree that it does not make sense here to call the destructor explicitly.

Comment: And this is a 3rd wrong statement in a row. While custom allocators are one of the cases for using placement new, it is not the only one. I think, this answer should be removed. The wording is obscure and misleading.

Comment: I wonder what the standard says about the status of the object once the destructor was manually called. Undefined behavior?

Comment: @flatmouse I'd agree to change "never" into "never (unless you know very well you need to because you're handling the life-time and allocation of your objects yourself, which, typically, is a not very C++-like approach)". Would that appease you? (I kind of doubt I'll appease Sergey)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, your hunch is correct. Cosmetic change as above wouldn't make it a good answer, and there is already a very good duplicate. I counsel removal.

Comment: @SergeyA the duplicate aspect is a valid argument!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think it would appease the c++ forces that us mere mortals can only dream about. It would also make it the only answer where others were to timid to answer. :)

Comment: @flatmouse, the standard is very clear on this part: *Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists*

Comment: So, I'm stuck between SergeyA's pretty wise approach of "better say nothing than something questionable if there's another, good, answer to a similar question already" and flatmouse's "giving an answer with explicit advise not to shoot one's own foot to a beginner question might be worth the frowning it induces with people who actually know their C++".

Comment: @SergeyA: re: standard: is that a "passive" *is invoked (by the runtime after lifetime has ended)* or a "temporal" *is invoked (no matter who invoked it*? Could you give us a link to the standard text?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, don't worry too much about it :) Just follow your heart.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you answer adds something new you can always add it to the dupe target so everyone gets to see it instead of it sitting here in isolation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, you can find this wording in 12.4 / 15. I do not have linkable standard in front of me.

Comment: @SergeyA Here you go: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#15.  Do note is is pulled from the latest draft.

Comment: @NathanOliver: good point (answering original question), and thanks for the reference. Hm, I must agree this sounds much like *…is invoke (no matter who or what invoked it)*, but then the object would no longer exist, and accessing things of non-existing objects *should* not be UB, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Why would accessing something that does not exist not be UB?  It would be like using `int * foo; std::cout << *foo;`.  What `foo` points to does not exist and this is UB.  Trying to use the object after it is destroyed is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver: oh, true.