# Exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0x148F854. (C++ Destructor Error)

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

```
case 4: //  ----------------------------------------    Delete Customer
                cout << "Enter your Customer ID:" << endl;
                cin >> exist_id;
                for (int i = 0; i <= cnum; i++) {
                    if (c[i].C_ID() == exist_id) {
                        cc = 't'; // check to set customer found.

                        c[i].~customer(); // error occurs here

                        c[i].id(NULL);
                        cout << "Deletion Successful" << endl << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                };

                if (cont(cc) == false) {
                    cout << "CUSTOMER NOT FOUND" << endl << endl;
                }
                cc = 'f';
                //system("CLS");
                break;
```

I the above case i am having the **Exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0x148F854**. Error.

The code ran perfectly on 2-3-2020. But today this error arises while deleting the customer from an array.

[Visual Studio Error alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtre8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructors in C++ are called by default when the object dies/destroys to handle the not needed allocated memory for the first place and it shouldn't be called anywhere else.

In your case, I think that the best practice to do is to create a member function `delete_customer` in `customer` class that has the exact code in the destructor.

Or, to not repeat the code twice, you can call `delete_customer` function in the destructor to be called when the object dies.

Hope this will fix your issue!

Comment: your fix might work yes. But the code worked by just copying it into another C++ empty project. This fix confused me more lol.

Comment: @SaeedRehman Just because it appears to work sometimes doesn't mean it's correct. You should not be explicitly calling the destructor unless you're in one of the situations mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187006/9254539). You probably have a load of undefined behavior that happens to appear to work.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @BessieTheCow

Comment: Alright I'll look into this topic in detail. Thanks @BessieTheCow.