# C++ member array destructor

Tags: c++, arrays, class, destructor, member

I am struggeling with a memory error when calling the destructor of the folowing class:

```
class Point
{
private:
    int dimensions;
    double *values;

public:
    Point(const int dim);
    Point(const Point &that);
    ~Point();
    Point &operator=(const Point &that);
    double operator[](int i) const;
    int dim() const;
    void print();
};
```

The constructor is implemented as follows

```
Point::Point(const int dim) : dimensions(dim)
{
    values = new double[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        values[i] = 0.0;
    }
};
```

and the destructor as

```
Point::~Point()
{
    delete[] values;
};
```

Unfortunately, when trying to execute the main function

```
int main()
{
    Point pt1(3);
    pt1.print();
    std::cout << pt1[0] << std::endl;
    pt1.~Point();
}
```

I get a runtime error stating *free(): double free detected in tcache 2*. When I run the code through valgrind, It seems like the pointer *values* is delted twice (*total heap usage: 3 allocs, 4 frees,...*), which does not make any sense for me.

It's been a while since I wrote some c++ for the last time, so I have no clue what I am missing/skrewing up here and would appreciaty any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't call the destructor manually. `pt1` has automatic storage duration so it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope, which calls the destructor. By calling it yourself you are causing it to actually run twice, which isn't allowed. It's extremely rare to have to call the destructor explicitly like a function.

Comment: Which C++ textbook offers an example of using a destructor, explicitly, like this? This looks like a typo in the textbook, that should be corrected.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau Still looking for a duplicate. Edit : I think I found a good duplicate.

Comment: Non- duplicate, but good reading: [Is calling destructor manually always a sign of bad design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187006/is-calling-destructor-manually-always-a-sign-of-bad-design)